# matplotlib scaled y axis

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I'm using matplotlib to display several data sets in a single plot. I would like to have multiple "external" y axes for the secondary data, and would like those axes to have the same range, but be scaled shorter than that of the main plot axis.

[Current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8erPv.png)

[Desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2pHM.png)

I'm creating the additional y axes using twinx() as describes in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11643893/2961550)

```
ax = day6Si.plot( 
  'time', 'pce_rolling'
)

dataPsc[ dataPsc.day == 5 ].plot( 
  'time', 'pce_rolling', ax = ax 
)

ax3 = ax.twinx()
ax3.fill_between( 
  day6Si.time, 0, day6Si.temperature
)

rspine = ax3.spines[ 'right' ]
rspine.set_position( ( 'axes', 1.15 ) )
ax3.set_frame_on( True )
ax3.patch.set_visible( False )
ax3.set_ylim( bottom = 0 )


ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.fill_between( 
  day6Si.time, 0, day6Si.intensity
)

rspine = ax2.spines[ 'right' ]
rspine.set_position( ( 'axes', 1.05 ) )
ax2.set_frame_on( True )
ax2.patch.set_visible( False )
ax2.set_ylim( bottom = 0 )
```

***MCV Example***

```
td = np.linspace( 0, np.pi, 101 )
df = pd.DataFrame( data = {
  'main': np.sin( td ),
  'secondary': 10 * np.sin( td )
} )

ax = df.plot( df.index.values, 'main' )

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.fill_between( 
  df.index.values, 0, df.secondary, 
  facecolor = '#a05050', 
  label = 'Secondary'
)

rspine = ax2.spines[ 'right' ]
rspine.set_position( ( 'axes', 1.05 ) )
ax2.set_frame_on( True )
ax2.patch.set_visible( False )
ax2.set_ylim( bottom = 0 )
ax2.set_ylabel( 'Secondary' )

ax.set_ylim( 0, 1 )
ax.legend( [ 'Main', 'Secondary' ] )
```

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidG I have added a MCV. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to making this work is to manipulate the Bbox of each of the axes. This solution builds off [this advice for creating multiple y axes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11643893/2961550)

*mpl = matplotlib, np = numpy, pd = pandas*

1. Create the main axes, `ax`.
2. Get the [Bbox](https://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox) of the axes, using `ax.get_position()`, then get the bounding points, `axpos`, using `get_points()`.
3. Create the secondary axes, `ax2`, using [`ax.twinx()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html).
4. Create the Bbox for `ax2`, `ax2pos`, using `mpl.transforms.Bbox( np.copy( axpos ) )`. Be sure to create a copy of the original Bbox points, otherwise both will be modified.
5. Scale the secondary bounding box. This can be done by setting the `x1` property for horizontal scaling, or the `y1` property for vertical scaling. (e.g. `ax2pos.y1 = 0.5* ax2pos.y1`)
6. Set the bounding box of the secondary axis using [`set_position()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_position.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_position).
7. Turn off the top (or right, for horizontal scaling) [spine](https://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html) using `ax2.spines[ 'top' ].set_visible( False )`.

You may also have to consider:

- Toggling each axes [patch](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html) as to not paint over previously layers using `ax.patch.set_visible()`.
- Adjusting the drawing order of the axes using `ax.set_zorder()`.
- Due to the scaling you may have to adjust the bounding box used when saving the figure. This can be accomplished by creating another Bbox and passing it to [`savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html?highlight=savefig%20bbox) as the `bbox_inches` parameter.

***MCV Solution***

```
td = np.linspace( 0, np.pi, 101 )
df = pd.DataFrame( data = {
  'main': np.sin( td ),
  'secondary': 10 * np.sin( td )
} )

ax = df.plot( df.index.values, 'main' )
axpos = ax.get_position()

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2pos = mpl.transforms.Bbox( np.copy( axpos.get_points() ) ) # clone bounding box
ax2pos.y1 = ax2pos.y1 * 0.5 # scale y axis
ax2.set_position( ax2pos ) # set bounding box

ax2.fill_between( 
  df.index.values, 0, df.secondary, 
  facecolor = '#a05050', 
  label = 'Secondary'
)

ax2.spines[ 'right' ].set_position( ( 'axes', 1.05 ) )
ax2.spines[ 'top' ].set_visible( False )
ax2.set_frame_on( True )
ax2.patch.set_visible( False )
ax2.set_ylim( bottom = 0 )
ax2.set_ylabel( 'Secondary' )

ax.set_ylim( 0, 1 )
ax.legend( [ 'Main', 'Secondary' ] )
```

***Full Code Solution***

```
ax = day6Si.plot( 
   'time', 'pce_rolling', kind = 'line', label = 'Si',
    zorder = 40
)

dataPsc[ dataPsc.day == 5 ].plot( 
    'time', 'pce_rolling', kind = 'line', label = 'PSC',
    zorder = 30, ax = ax 
)

axpos = ax.get_position()
ax.set_zorder( 30 )
ax.patch.set_visible( False )

ax.set_xlim( 124.5, 141.5 )
ax.set_ylim( 10, 20 )
ax.set_ylabel( 'PCE (%)' )
ax.set_xlabel( 'Time' )
ax.set_xticklabels( [ '4', '6', '8', '10', '12', '14', '16', '18', '20' ] )
ax.legend( loc = 'upper right', bbox_to_anchor = ( 1, 1 ) )

# temperature
ax3 = ax.twinx()
ax3.fill_between( 
    day6Si.time, 0, day6Si.temperature, 
    facecolor = '#f0c5b5',
    label = 'Temperature (Rel)'
)

ax3pos = mpl.transforms.Bbox( np.copy( axpos.get_points() ) ) # clone bounding box
ax3pos.y1 = ax3pos.y1 * 0.5 # scale y axis
ax3.set_position( ax3pos ) # set bounding box

ax3.set_zorder( 10 )
ax3.spines[ 'right' ].set_position( ( 'axes', 1.025 ) ) # shift y axis
ax3.set_frame_on( True )
ax3.spines[ 'top' ].set_visible( False ) # remove top frame line
ax3.patch.set_visible( True )
ax3.set_ylim( bottom = 0, top = 60 )
ax3.set_ylabel( 'Temperature (C)' )

# intensity
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.fill_between( 
    day6Si.time, 0, day6Si.intensity, 
    facecolor = '#dddd99',
    label = 'Intensity (Rel)'
)

ax2pos = mpl.transforms.Bbox( np.copy( axpos.get_points() ) ) # clone bounding box
ax2pos.y1 = ax2pos.y1 * 0.33 # scale y axis
ax2.set_position( ax2pos ) # set bounding box

ax2.set_zorder( 20 )
ax2.spines[ 'right' ].set_position( ( 'axes', 1.125 ) ) # shift y asix
ax2.set_frame_on( True )
ax2.spines[ 'top' ].set_visible( False ) # remove top frame
ax2.patch.set_visible( False )
ax2.set_ylim( bottom = 0, top = 1 )
ax2.set_ylabel( 'Intensity (suns)' )

savebox = mpl.transforms.Bbox( [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 10* 1.15, 8 ] ] ) # bounding box in inches for saving
plt.gcf().savefig( figloc + '/day6.svg', format = 'svg', bbox_inches = savebox )
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyDUU.png)

**Update**

Due to an update in the matplotlib library, a small change must be made for this to work. Performing `ax.twinx()` no longer gives you control over the second axis, so it must be added to the figure manually.

*mpl = matplotlib, plt = matplotlib.pyplot, np = numpy, pd = pandas*

1. Create the main figure `fig` and axes `ax` using `plt.subplots()`
2. Create the Bbox as before in steps 2, 4, and 5.
3. Create the secondary axes `ax2a` using `fig.add_axes()`, with the desired bounding box.
4. Create the right y-axis by twinning `ax2a`, `ax2a.twinx()`.
5. Clean up the secondary axes.

You may also need to consider aligning the x-axes of your primary and secondary axes using `ax.set_xlim()` for both of them.

***MCV Solution***

```
td = np.linspace( 0, np.pi, 101 )
df = pd.DataFrame( data = {
  'main': np.sin( td ),
  'secondary': 10 * np.sin( td )
} )

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot( df.index.values, 'main', ax = ax )
axpos = ax.get_position()

ax2pos = mpl.transforms.Bbox( np.copy( axpos.get_points() ) )
ax2pos.y1 = ax2pos.y1 * 0.5 # scale y axis

ax2a = fig.add_axes( ax2pos ) # create secondary axes
ax2 = ax2a.twinx() # create right y-axis

ax2.fill_between( 
  df.index.values, 0, df.secondary, 
  facecolor = '#a05050', 
  label = 'Secondary'
)

ax2.spines[ 'right' ].set_position( ( 'axes', 1.05 ) )
ax2.spines[ 'top' ].set_visible( False )
ax2.set_frame_on( True )
ax2.patch.set_visible( False )
ax2.set_ylim( bottom = 0 )
ax2.set_ylabel( 'Secondary' )

# clean up secondary axes tick marks and labels
ax2a.tick_params( left = False, bottom = False )
ax2.tick_params( left = False, bottom = False )
ax2a.set_xticklabels( [] )
ax2a.set_yticklabels( [] )

ax.set_ylim( 0, 1 )
ax.legend( [ 'Main', 'Secondary' ] )
```